# Buck Converter Load Regulation

Tags: dc-dc-converter, buck, electronic-load, load-regulation

I have attached a schematic of a buck converter circuit I have designed. It's designed using a [LMR16030](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmr16030.pdf) IC.

Input voltage: 12-14V

Output voltage: 5V

Switching frequency: 1MHz

Output Current: 2A

I'm carrying out a load regulation test by connecting a electronic load at the output. As I increase load current from 0 to 1.5 A, the output voltage seems to decrease at a steady rate from 5V to 4.55V.

What can I do/change to ensure a steady output voltage? (max 2% deviation)

Comment: What's your PCB layout look like? Are all power traces sufficiently large to carry this much current? How much does the voltage on the feedback pin change over this current range?

Comment: Measure your output voltage directly from pin 7 of your IC to the top of R4. (Put your probes right on the pins/pad.)  Repeat the measurement and see what your regulation looks like.  Or as @Hearth said measure the feedback pin to pin 7 and see if that's changing.

Comment: @JohnD Measuring the feedback is probably better, because that specifically is what the IC is acting on. It can't see the output voltage directly at all.

Comment: @Hearth looks like the voltage at the feedback pin is pretty much constant. I have a 35 mil trace from the output cap C16 to the load pin. So seems like the trace is providing too much resistance?

Comment: @JohnD Voltage directly at R4 does seems pretty much constant.  So seems like the 35 mil trace is providing too much resistance?

Comment: How long is the 35 mil trace?

Comment: @Hearth The top of R4 should be the point that the converter is trying to regulate.  If it's not regulating there, it points to a layout issue with the ground of the feedback divider.  If it is regulating there it points to a layout issue between the top of R4 and the place the OP was measuring.  (Either on the output side or ground side).  Next step is to measure where he was measuring ground to pin 7 on the part, then from where he was measuring output voltage to the top of R4.  That will tell where the drop is occurring.

Comment: @Hearth the trace is almost 90mm long

Comment: Did you say how heavy the copper is?  If it's one ounce, that's a thin trace. 
 Measure the voltage drop along the trace -- but I suspect that's your problem.  At some small risk of creating some oddball instabilities, you could pick your feedback voltage off at the point of load.  It should be possible to simulate and/or calculate the impact of doing so on stability and transient response.  Or just make the trace way bigger, if you have the room.

Comment: You can also reinforce the trace with wire or extra solder if it's exposed.  Discussing the width of a trace is not relevant without discussing it's thickness and length.  If you're losing 0.45V at 1.5A, you have R=E/I=0.45V/1.5A=0.3\$\Omega\$ of unwanted resistance between your sense node and output. For 2% regulation(2%*5V=0.1V), you need to reduce this resistance to R=0.1V/1.5A=.0667\$\Omega\$ or less.  It would be wise to include an inspection of your ground path as well.

Comment: Also note that once you have your output voltage problem solved, you may wish to inspect the rest of the power  delivery circuit for other overloaded conductors, as you may be able to significantly increase efficiency.